# Smooth transition after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

When the submission is successful, meaning, there are no error messages that are generated, the form just disappears, kind of like thin air. However, I would like it to be a little smoother. I've tried fadeToggle() here and there but it didn't produce the effect that I wanted. Anybody have a solution to this problem?

This is the code that I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
        var errorMessage="";
        if(!isValidEmailAddress($("#emailAddress").val())) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            errorMessage = errorMessage+"<br />Invalid Email Address";
        }
        $("#error").html(errorMessage); //I tried putting the fadeToggle() here.
    });
});
<form id="validationForm">    
    <input id="emailAddress" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Try [jquery fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) with the duration 900.

Comment: Try to use slideup or read something about jquery animate

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: But I'm not sure where I should put the fadeOut...

Comment: You need to delay the submit until de animation has finished, otherwise the page si submited and you don't see the effect. You can do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/mvkL0ue0/